# Service Worker recurring

Tags: javascript, browser, push-notification, service-worker, background-sync

Can i make a service worker, that run in background and poll the server at specific interval and return response or show notification(push notification) when chrome browser is closed. I am working for a website, that ask for service worker permission and sync the request at specific intervals in background based on request received from server show the notification.

**Edit 1:**
As of now i can see chrome is working on this, but the [post](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) is too old Dec 2015. They have written it that they will introduce it in first half of 2016. It is not available till yet.

> We're aiming to ship background sync to a stable version of Chrome in
>   the first half of 2016. But we’re also working on a variant, “periodic
>   background sync”. This will allow you to request a “periodicsync”
>   event restricted by time interval, battery state and network state.
>   This would require user permission, of course, but it will also be
>   down to the will of the browser for when and how often these events
>   fire. E.g., a news site could request to sync every hour, but the
>   browser may know you only read that site at 07:00, so the sync would
>   fire daily at 06:50. This idea is a little further off than one-off
>   syncing, but it’s coming.

Comment: With pure javascript it's impossible, every script stops when the browser stops

Comment: @Bálint then how cnn.com is pushing the notifications

Comment: They do it when Chrome is running. You simply can't do it when the user closes the browse

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/

Comment: @Bálint Yes, i had looked at it, its just push notification. I want to trigger sync event at regular intervals. So it polls the server(when browser closed) and get me new information available.

Comment: Found this.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PeriodicSyncManager. but it is not available yet for any web browser

Comment: That still doesn't work when the browser is closed, because it runs in a WebWorker. Please understand, **JavaScript doesn't run natively, it needs a browser, no matter what you do, when it closes, everything stops**. The only thing you can do is to literally install a virus-like program on the user's computer, but then we can't help you, and it's also illegal